# not able to Converting encoding western european iso 8859 1 in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

I want to use `encoding western european iso 8859 1` in C# for that I have tried below mentioned code and it's converted but at some value it will put ? can anyone please let me know the way for encoding

currently I am using below menioned method for Encoding.

```
 XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(ds); //ds is a dataset which contain my data
        string strpath = Server.MapPath("Templates/Major.xsl");
        XslTransform xslTran = new XslTransform();
        xslTran.Load(strpath);

        string stroutput = Server.MapPath("Output/") + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUploadMajor.PostedFile.FileName) + ".xml";

     XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stroutput, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, writer);

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(stroutput)));
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(stroutput);
            Response.End();
```

currently I got below menioned OP

[image]

my excepted OP should be

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show the result you are expecting

Comment: It seems the char in question is a special dot which can`t be expressed by using the desired encoding. Reformat the output to use another (maybe multiplicator)

Comment: my Data in fi-FI Culture so I have to put . for decimal seperator.

Comment: That is: you want to format numeric data to a localized format in an XML file??? No! Use 9600000, and then it is the task of the UI on the other side to show it in local format.
And by the way, the character you show as a thousands separator in the image is NOT a decimal dot!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no corresponding character in the encoding western european iso 8859 1,
Why you have to use this specific encoding?

if not required ,you can use some more common encoding like UTF8

Comment: my data is in fi-FI culture and in fi-FI long value should be 9.600.000